# Stripping blocks of text from huge text file

Tags: sed, awk

I've been tasked with something quite painful and I was wondering if anyone could help.

Our vendor has provided an SNMP mib file (txt).  Unfortunately, an awful lot of this file is outdated and needs to be stripped out for our monitoring app.

I've been trying to do this by hand, but it's over 800,000 lines long, and it's sapping my will to live.

The structure is something like:

```
-- /*********************************************************************************/
-- /* MIB table for Hardware                                                        */
-- /* Valid from: 543.44                                                            */
-- /* Deprecated from: 600.3                                                        */
-- /*********************************************************************************/

Some text 
some text 
Some text

-- /*********************************************************************************/
-- /* MIB table for Hardware                                                        */
-- /* Valid from: 543.44                                                            */
-- /*********************************************************************************/

Some text 
some text 
Some text

-- /*********************************************************************************/
-- /* MIB table for Hardware                                                        */
-- /* Valid from: 364.44                                                            */
-- /* Deprecated from: 594.3                                                        */
-- /*********************************************************************************/
```

Repeated at random and ad nauseum

What I'm thinking, is a script that would:

find the text "Deprecated from"
then

```
delete that line, 
delete the preceding 3 lines, 
delete the following one line, 
delete then all following lines until the next
"-- /*********************************************************************************/"
```

Does this make sense?  Is this kind of thing possible, or am I only dreaming?

Thankyou!

Comment: Deleting from the `Deprecated` to the `/**...` is fairly easy, deleting the 3 previous lines that's somewhat more difficult.

Comment: I think handling this with sed or awk would sap _my_ will to live.  Perl or some other language that allows you to parse around line boundaries is a better choice for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I just realized I read your question wrong, even after having been upvoted a few times. My response before was off! It should now be more correct, but with some **additional assumptions**. Simple solutions can only get you so far!

This might be able to help you out, with a few assumptions:

```
cat -s data | awk -vFS='\n' -vRS='\n\n' '/Deprecated from/ { getline; next } 1'
```

The `cat` command is simply there to squeeze out excess newlines, so `awk` can operate more easily. As for `awk`, the `-vFS='\n'` tells it that fields are separated by newlines, and `-vRS='\n\n'` tells it that records are separated by two newlines in a row. Then `/Deprecated from/` finds records that have that text, and `{ getline; next }` reads in the next record after it, and causes it to move on. `1` is a shortcut to print lines that reach the following point.

**This will assume the following**:

- All comment and text blocks are separated by at least one blank line on either side
- There are only comment blocks and text blocks interspersed evenly
- There aren't blank lines within the text blocks

So it might not be quite perfect for you. If these assumptions are okay, it makes `awk` a nice choice for this job, as you can see: the script is tiny!

```
$ cat -s data | awk -vFS='\n' -vRS='\n\n' '/Deprecated from/ { getline; next } 1'
-- /*********************************************************************************/
-- /* MIB table for Hardware                                                        */
-- /* Valid from: 543.44                                                            */
-- /*********************************************************************************/
Some text
some text
Some text
```

In addition, as you can see, the newlines that remain get pushed out. To aid this, you could modify the command like this:

```
$ cat -s data | awk -vFS='\n' -vRS='\n\n' '/Deprecated from/ { getline; next } { printf "%s\n\n", $0 }'
-- /*********************************************************************************/
-- /* MIB table for Hardware                                                        */
-- /* Valid from: 543.44                                                            */
-- /*********************************************************************************/

Some text
some text
Some text
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '$!N;$!N;:a;$q;N;/Deprecated from/!{P;s/^[^\n]*\n//;ba};$d;$!N;$d;s/.*//;:b;$d;N;/^\n-- \/\*\+\/$/!{s/.*//;bb};D' file
```

Here's a slightly easier solution (less efficient as it takes 2 passes):

```
awk '/Deprecated from/{a=NR-3;getline;next};a>0 && /^-- \/\*+\/$/{b=NR-1;print a "," b "d";a=b=0};END{if(a>0)print a ",$d"}' file |
sed -f - file
```

Comment: I want so badly for that to work, but it doesn't for me. I get nothing printed.

Comment: @DanFego Oops! left a debugging aid in. Removed it, try again.

Comment: It's a messy thicket of letters and symbols, but it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `vim` macro.

1. Bring up the file:  `$ vim filename`
2. Press `q a`   to record macro in register `a`
3. Type `/Deprecated from:` followed by Enter  (to search for text)
4. `3k` (to go up 3 lines)
5. `4dd`  (delete this line and the next 3)
6. `d/\*\*\*\*\*\*`  (to delete lines up to the splats)
7. (if necessary) press `dd` (to delete the current line)
8. Press `q` to end macro recording
9. Type `1000000@a`  (to execute the macro a million times)

Answer (score 1):

I very much agree with the comment about using another scripting language to solve this.  Ruby, Perl, or Python would probably be better.  But for fun, here is an ugly Awk script that does it.  The matches could maybe use some work if they are not appropriate.  But is implements a simple state machine.  It tracks if it is in a header or not and determines if it is deprecated.  It stores the header lines in an array.  When it gets to the end of the header, it prints the header (if not deprecated).  When not in a header, it prints the lines if the preceding section was not deprecated.

```
{
   if ( $0 ~ /-- \/\**+\// ) {
      # This matches one of the -- /*********...****/ lines
      if ( headercount > 0 ) {
         # this must be the closing line in the header
         if ( !deprecated ) {
            for ( i = 0; i < headercount; i++ ) {
                print headers[i]
            }
            # print closing line
            print
         } # if not deprecated

         headercount = 0
      }
      else {
         # must be starting a new section
         headers[0] = $0
         headercount = 1
         deprecated = 0
      }
   }
   else {
      if ( headercount == 0 ) {
         # not in a header section - print if not deprecated
         if ( !deprecated ) {
            print
         }
      }
      else {
         # in a header section - track if it is a deprecated section
         if ( $0 ~ /Deprecated from/ ) {
            deprecated = 1
         }
         # store the header info to dump when we hit the end
         headers[headercount++] = $0;
      }

   }
}
```